# Text form with attached/prefixed drop down

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I am trying to make a one-lined "Mobile number" form with country code dropdown attached on the left part of it, like shown on the image ->:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwQsK.png)

Sorry if this is another redundant question, I really couldn't find any answer for it. Will appreciate any reply, big thanks in advance and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `prefix` property inside the `TextField` decoration:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefix: // put you widget here
  ),
),
```

Comment: In my experience it puts the prefix on the same level as text, inside the space between paddings. Maybe I am doing it wrong. I decided to create my own Widget for that out of various parental Widgets, let's see how it goes, will leave an answer here if it works well.